# XPage jdbcRowSet + repeat control: In place changes not persisted in Oracle 10 DB

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to create an “endless form”, where the user can edit an RDBMS table's column values directly in the form (i.e. without opening a separate “edit form” that allows to edit a single row). I am using a XPages repeat control bound to a jdbcRowSet which accesses a simple PERSON table in an Oracle 10 DB (id number primary key, first/last name, plus some additional columns not exposed in the form).

Displaying the data and editing it works as expected, but persisting the changes back to the DB fails persistently, but without an error message. In the source code below one can see the ways I have tried to tell the data source to save the changes made, but to no avail. 
(Using the same code with a Notes datasource works as expected and persists the changes).

How would I get the jdbcRowSet to persist the changes in the form ?

Thanks in advance for any help, 
Martin

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp=“http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core”

xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<xp:this.data>
    <!-- <xp:dominoView var="view1Ld" viewName="AuthorView"></xp:dominoView> -->
    <xe:jdbcRowSet var="view1" connectionName="oracle10"
        sqlTable="PERSON">
    </xe:jdbcRowSet>
    <xe:jdbcQuery var="jdbcQuery1"></xe:jdbcQuery>
</xp:this.data>


<xp:panel id="panel0">

    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{view1}" var="rpt">
        <xp:panel id="panelDocData">
            <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{rpt.id}"></xp:inputText>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText2"
                value="#{rpt.first_name}">
            </xp:inputText>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText3" value="#{rpt.last_name}"
                showReadonlyAsDisabled="true">
            </xp:inputText>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText5"
                defaultValue="#{rpt.last_name}">
            </xp:inputText>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:repeat>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText4" value="#{view1.last_name}"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Save" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:view1.acceptChanges()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Simply Save" id="button3">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:save></xp:save>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Submit" id="button4">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:confirm
                    message="Are you sure you want to persist the changes in the database ?">
                </xp:confirm>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Save Document" id="button5">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument var="view1"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button id="button6">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[Save Datasource]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:rpt.acceptChanges()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Save View DS" id="button7">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:view1.acceptChanges()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Save View DS 2" id="button8">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:view1.rpt.acceptChanges()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:panel>
<xp:br></xp:br>
```

Comment: Is your database set to auto commit, or do you have to do it manually?

Comment: Also can you use a tool like WinSQL to verify that your user access has the permissions to perform updates?

Comment: @autocmmit: I did not change the default, so it is auto-commit

Comment: @update grant: It's the schema user (also this would throw)

Comment: Are using your own UPDATE statement or the now available @jdbcUpdate. Show the code you are using regardless of which is used.

Comment: I have posted all of my code already: I am using a jdbcRowSet updateable data source. To trigger the write back of the changed data in the data source I have tried several approaches bound s´to multiple "save" buttons. E.g. the first button using javascript:view1.acceptChanges() tells the view to persist all its data sources. This works for a Domino view, but not for the Oracle 10 table.

Comment: I know that in the relational XPages sample they are opening a new, single entity/row form to edit data. This is not what I am trying to do here. I am trying to reproduce the more RAD-like editable endless form seen e.g. in Powerbuilder, Delphi or even Access, where you have no boilerplate code whatsoever - you just bind the form controls to the data source and bind a save event to e.g. a button, which persists the data (since my PERSON table has a primary key, I would have assumed the data source would be able to handle this automatically).